# How to find a close form expression in terms generating functions for the triple summation

Tags: computational-mathematics

Given $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i=A(z)$$ and $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty b_i z^i=B(z)$$ and $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty c_i z^i=C(z)$$ Find $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_j \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_kc_{k+j-i} z^i$ in terms of the generating functions $A(z),B(z),C(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $i=(j)+(k)-(j+k-i)$, the triple sum is 
$$\sum\limits_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}a_\alpha b_\beta c_\gamma z^{\alpha+\beta-\gamma}=A(z)B(z)C(1/z).$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please see this also $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i=A(z)$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty b_j z^j=B(z)$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^{-k}=C(1/z)$ Then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_ib_jc_{i+j-k} z^k=$?

Comment: What are you asking me to do?

Comment: Whether this expression is same as the previous one $A(z)B(z)C(1/z)$

Comment: As $A(z)B(z)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{i}a_jb_{i-j}$ then what is the expression for $A(z)B(z)C(1/z)$